# Microsoft Teams bot not sending notifications when deploying new version to azure

Tags: .net, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, teams-toolkit

I'm developing a Microsoft Teams bot using Visual Studio (.NET) and Teams Toolkit.

When I first publish my Teams bot, it works fine (I am testing it using http triggers). I am following this process in Teams Toolkit:

1. Prepare Teams App Dependencies
2. Provision in the Cloud
3. Deploy to the Cloud
4. Open Teams Developer Portal to Publish

But whenever I update the source code and increase the version in manifest.json, my bot does not send notifications using the same triggers (following the same process above to publish any update).
I have to uninstall the bot from my user and then install it again for it to be recognized (which I do not want to be doing manually).

Can you please help me with this?
Am I missing something?

I've tried finding documentation on Microsoft end to try and fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using the default local file storage, Azure web app and Azure Functions clean up the local file during a restart or redeploy. You need to implement your own storage to persist the conversation reference.

You can refer to [the Add Storage part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#add-storage) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @KIMI.

That is exactly what was happening.
I had to implement my own blob storage to persist the conversation reference (based on interface IConversationReferenceStore).